# Defining variables at the beginning of function and "fprintf"

Tags: c, variables, scanf

I'd like your help with couple of things I'm not sure of them, even-though the compiler doesn't complain about them:

Here I need to write a program which gets input and output, in the input file were stored integers which I don't know their amount divided by spaces, I need to read these numbers, sort them by the sum of digits comparison and print out the sorted numbers in the output file. this is what I wrote, after that a couple of short question about this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


int myComp(const void *a, const void *b){

    int x=(*(int*)a);
    int y=(*(int*)b);
    int sumForx=0;
    int sumFory=0;

    while (x){
        sumForx=sumForx+(x%10);
        x=(x-(x%10))/10;
    }

    while (y){
            sumFory=sumFory+(y%10);
            y=(y-(y%10))/10;
        }
    if (x>y) return 1;
    else if (x<y) return -1;
    else return 0;



}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    FILE* inFile;
    FILE* outFile;
    int size=0;
    int tmp;

    if (argc!=3) {
        printf("Please enter 3 arguments");
        assert(0);
    }
    inFile=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (inFile==NULL) {
        printf("path to the input file has not found");
        assert(0);
    }
    outFile=fopen(argv[2], "w");

    if (outFile==NULL) {
        printf("path to the output file has not found");
        assert(0);
    }

    while (fscanf(inFile, "%d", &tmp)==1) {
        size++;
    }

    int arr[size];

    fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    int i=0;
    while (fscanf(inFile, "%d", &tmp)==1) {
        arr[0]=tmp;
        i++;
    }

    qsort(arr,size,sizeof(int),myComp);

    int j;
    for (j=0;j<size;j++){
        fprintf(outFile,"%d",arr[j]);
        fprintf(outFile,"%c",' ');
    }

    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);

    return 1;

}
```

1. I kept define new variables during the main, in different places- I can recall that I shouldn't do that since all variables must be defined at the beginning of the function, unless there are local variables of inner functions/brackets, and this is not the case here- but still the compiler is fine with this- what's the correct thing to do?
2. If the answer the (1) is "you must define all variables at the beginning of the function"- in my case, I must define dynamic `int* arr` and allocate space for it after I computed size, otherwise I can't use `int arr[size]` since size is computed after all the variables have defined already, include the integer array.

3.I want to enter a space between these numbers while being printed to the file, is `fprintf(outFile,"%c",' ');` correct after putting integer every time?

4.any other correction would be gladly welcome!

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If gcc, then by default gcc should allow placing variables anywhere in the function.

Comment: I'm not really sure, I use Eclipse.

Comment: If you're on a GNU/Linux box, you are probably using gcc

Answer (score 1):

The requirement to declare all variables at the beginning of a function dates back the the pre-previous version of the standard (C89, which was outdated by C99, which was outdated by C11).

Since you are using a variable-length array (`arr[size]`), which wasn't possible in that pre-previous version of the standard, you are obviously using a halfway-decent compiler that doesn't stick to restrictions no longer applying since 1999. ;-)

As for printing a space, `fprintf( outfile, " " )` or (even better) `fputc( ' ', outfile )` would do.

As for further corrections, I have a habit of not reading / commenting on uncommented source. You have a coding style with which I violently disagree, but at least you're consistent in applying it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. This depends on the version of C you are using. If you use ANSI C (c89) you will get warnings or errors about this. But most (if not all) modern compilers support declarations almost anywhere in the code.
2. This again depends on your compiler. Old compilers couldn't allocate static arrays like that, modern compilers can.
3. `fprintf(outFile, " ");` is perfectly legal too.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using gcc, it will allow you to place variables anywhere in the function. However, other compilers (e.g. MSVC 2008) follow *ansi c* i.e c89 and probably will complain about it. The correct thing to do depends on your application. If you want it to be portable across compilers, declarations should come before statements.
2. This is also compiler and C standards specific, so reasoning similar to point 1 applies.
3. For this, your code seems fine but I use something like:

   `fprintf(outFile, "%d ", arr[j]);`

to achieve similar functionality in a single line.

Comment: MSVC not keeping up-to-date with relevant standards is the problem of the compiler, not the problem of the coding style. The right thing to do is drop MSVC and using an up-to-date compiler, instead of crippling your source / style by keeping backward compatibility.

Comment: @DevSolar: I agree with you, that's why I specified that the correct thing to do depends on the application. If strict ANSI C conformance is not a hard requirement, you can use features from c99 but some projects (e.g. legacy code) might still have that restriction.

Comment: Hmmm... the only reason for having to maintain strict conformance with a 23-year-old standard that I could imagine would be the unavailability of newer compilers, because I don't know of any significant incompatibilities of C99 with C89. And I don't know a single platform that doesn't have *at least* a C99 compiler available.

Comment: @DevSolar e.g. I once had to fix a bug in a windows app that was being compiled with MSVC by virtue of legacy. So I followed the ANSI C standard while adding code for that fix because the build had to be tested on MSVC before we could ship the app.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** Declaring variables anywhere in the function body is fine as long as you are on a compiler that supports the C99 standard or later. Earlier compilers required that you declared variables at the beginning of a block scope, as you say.

You can do even better than in your code however, by limiting the scope of some of the variables even more. Instead of:

```
int j;
for (j = 0; j < size; j++) { ... }
```

You can simplify this to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { ... }
```

Which also limits the scope where `j` is accessible to the block following the `for` statement.

**2:** Dynamically sized arrays are only supported in C99 and later, so the code would not compile on a compiler that does not support the newer standard.

**3:** You can simply add the extra space to the initial format string:

```
fprintf(outfile, "%d ", arr[j]);
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, the function which you use with "qsort" must have the signature as I wrote for MyComp.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Please enter 3 arguments");
```

The executable name is usually not referred to as an argument so this would normally be

```
printf("Please enter 2 arguments - input filename and output filename e.g.:\n");
printf("%s file1.txt file2.txt\n",argv[0]);
```

This

```
arr[0]=tmp;
```

should be

```
arr[i]=tmp;
```